# A King's Short Walk

Tags: mathematics, checkerboard, primes

Place the numbers 1 to 25 on the cells of this board so that any two consecutive numbers occupy cells that are horizontally, vertically or diagonally adjacent. Prime numbers should occupy shaded cells.

[image: enter image descri## Heading ##ption here]

Comment: I don't get it. A bishop's walk could only visit half the cells. Shouldn't it be a *King's* walk?

Comment: There are 8568 solutions (counting rotations and flips). These could be grouped into 192 permutations for the prime cells. The number 23 occurs in the middle ~72% of the time.

Comment: @EricDuminil Right! Fixed!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like so?

> [image]

The beginning seems almost forced (apart from symmetries), and the rest just fell in place on the first attempt.

Comment: Almost but not quite (forced, that is): 25 3 4 5 6 // 2 24 22 21 7 // 14 1 23 8 20 // 13 15 16 9 19 // 12 11 10 17 18

Answer (score 4):

As there are quite a few possible solutions and seeing that it is "A *Bishop's* Walk" here is one that tries to use as many bishopy (aka diagonal)  moves as possible:

> ```
>       1     3    25    23  - 22
>       |  /  |     |  /     /
>       2     4    24    21    19
>                \           X  |
>       8     6  -  5    18    20
>       |  X                 \
>       7     9    12    15    17
>          /     /     X     \  |
>      10  - 11    14  - 13    16
> ```